# Represent all numbers as numbers between $0$ and $1$

Tags: real-analysis

I have proved that between every $2$ distinct real numbers, there exists infinitely many other real numbers. A question came up to my mind: Now that we have an infinite number of real numbers between let's say, $0$ and $1$, can we represent all real numbers as numbers between $0$ and $1$ too? In other words, can the set of all real numbers be put in one-to-one correspondence with $[0,1]$? If we can, why? And is there a way to "choose" the number which shows the real number that we wanted to represent it as a number between $0$ and $1$? For example, how can we find the number in $[0,1]$ that represents $\pi$?

Comment: Yes, you can. There exixts a real number whose binary representation begins with the complete texts of the Library of Congress, say, in ASCII, followed by the same as 600 dpi PDF scans, followed by how Shakespeare would have written Romeo and Juliet if he had been born Tanzania in 1950. And then some (in fact a rational yould suffice for any finite requirement).

Comment: you still count them with numbers great than 0 and 1. I think it's kind of like saying that everything between you and me can be represented by you and me.

Comment: Are you saying that $\frac12$ is greater than $0$ and $1,$ for example?

Comment: well, I think what I meant is that we can label everything in the world with a number between 0 and 1. and this labeling thing is actually a counting process. I didn't mean 1/2 is larger than 1. but what 1/2 and 1/3 represent is larger than 1.    I think Cameron Buie's answer helps a lot.

Comment: This is not so bad a question as to be closed as off-topic in my opinion, at least if we take it as a "popular math" kind of question, but I would be really surprised if this is not a duplicate... Not sure how to find it, though.

Comment: I wonder why should it be considered as off-topic too.

Comment: And please ask it in the comments if it is "unclear for you what I am asking."

Comment: It just depends on what you mean by "everything in the world".  If the number of such things is finite or countably infinite, or even has the same cardinality as the reals, then obviously this is true.  But do you consider "the set of irrational numbers" as a thing in the world?  What about arbitrary sets of real numbers?  If all sets of real numbers are "things in the world" (they're certainly things in the world of mathematics!), then the things in the world are too numerous to be put in a one-to-one correspondence with $[0,1]$.

Comment: So you are saying that the set of all real numbers cannot be put in one-to-one correspondence with $[0,1]$?

Comment: "can the set of all real numbers be put in one-to-one correspondence with [0,1]?" Yes. "If we can, is there a way to "choose" the number which shows each real number?" Explain "to show each real number".

Comment: Use $x\mapsto(1+x+|x|)/(2+2|x|)$ a a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1)$. Tweak it on the integers to get a bijection with $[0,1]$. Then $\pi$ is "represented" by $(1+2\pi)/(2+2\pi)\approx0.87927\ldots$

Comment: Oh, That's exactly what I wanted. It's better that you post this as an answer if my question reopens, though.

Comment: $\tan(x)$ also works (or rather, it works for $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, but a quick argument gives you a bijection $[0, 1]\rightarrow [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$).

Answer (score 3):

In the sense that there are only finitely-many "things" in the world, absolutely. In fact, we can represent each thing in the world as a number of the form $\frac{1}{n+1}$ for some positive integer $n$.

However, there are still a prohibitively large number of things in the world, so actually *choosing* such representation is impossible in practice, though possible in theory. (And if you count electrons as "things," then it's impossible even with unlimited time.)

Comment: Thanks for the note, I added another question of "choosing" them as  you stated here.